# Cocos2d-x HockeyApp integration

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.x

I tried to integrate HockeyApp in my cocos2d-x project, using following link:-
http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-ndk-early-access

But it gives me following error when I tried to run ndk-build command

```
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:47:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc'
 using AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc = int (*)(int bufID, int prio, const char *tag,
       ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:47:7: error: 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc' has not been declared
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:47:33: error: expected ';' before '=' token
 using AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc = int (*)(int bufID, int prio, const char *tag,
                                 ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:47:33: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:53:1: error: 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc' does not name a type
 AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc g_android_log_buf_write = nullptr;
 ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc: In function 'void logger::initializeCrashLogWriter()':
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:3: error: 'g_android_log_buf_write' was not declared in this scope
   g_android_log_buf_write = reinterpret_cast<AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc>(
   ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:46: error: expected type-specifier before 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc'
   g_android_log_buf_write = reinterpret_cast<AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc>(
                                              ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:46: error: expected '>' before 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc'
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:46: error: expected '(' before 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc'
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:60:46: error: 'AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:61:54: error: expected ')' before ';' token
       dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "__android_log_buf_write"));
                                                      ^
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc: In function 'int logger::writeToCrashLog(const char*)':
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/log/log.cc:68:7: error: 'g_android_log_buf_write' was not declared in this scope
   if (g_android_log_buf_write) {
       ^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/breakpad_client/src/client/linux/log/log.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Could you let me know on which platform did you call the ndk-build? Which compiler did you use? I am still trying to reproduce your issue, and I will get back to you ASAP. In the meanwhile, maybe you could try to enable c++11 support on ndk to compile your app via adding "APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11" in the Application.mk file.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.6.3 doesn't support C++11 type aliases:

in

Breakpad\src\client\linux\log\log.cc

replace

```
using AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc = int (*)(int bufID, int prio, const char *tag,const char *text);
```

with

```
typedef int (*AndroidLogBufferWriteFunc)(int bufID, int prio, const char *tag,const char *text);
```